# Print Unicode string on command prompt in VC++

Tags: visual-c++

```
 CString strFoo = _T("Привет"); 
 const WCHAR * pszFoo = (const WCHAR *)strFoo; 
 wcout << "Value " << pszFoo1 << "\n";
```

failed to print "Привет" value in windows command prompt.

Comment: What does it print?  That may help to determine what your issue is.

Comment: Aside from the fact that Windows' command prompt doesn't seem to display Unicode glyphs well, if at all, is your file saved as UTF-8? If it is, have you tried looking up the Unicode code points for your test string and used Unicode escape sequences instead of actual text? The only safe characters for a string literal are ASCII due to file encodings. Have you tried redirecting the output to a file and opening the file to verify it is printing the string you think it should be?